# Tool to replace json by json

Tags: java, json

I'm looking for a java tool which allows me to replace json by json. The main idea is to put in the first json file a reference to the second file like this :

File1.json :

```
{ 
  "name" : "test",
  "include" : "File2.json"
}
```

File2.json :

```
{
  "age" : 54
}
```

I'd like to have this output :

```
{
   "name" : "test",
   "age" : 54
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about what I can use ?

Comment: You can use Java and JSON. Really. Take the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) package and build a tool yourself that does this.

Comment: And BTW, why does it have to be a Java tool?

Comment: If I don't find any solution I will develop my own tool but before that I wanted to know if there was some kind of tool to do this. It has to be a jar because I'm working on android so it will be much easier to integrate it.